# Lock / barrel malfunctioning

Tags: lock

Kwikset lock, when depressing exterior thumb lever, Barrel will not detract all way[image]

Comment: The first thing I'd check is whether or not the mechanism is worn, damaged, or just dirty and that is preventing the bolt from fully withdrawing.

Comment: those two parts aren't connected. i bet pressing the level makes the whole door move closer or further from the jamb by releasing the knob latch. fix the door alignment and check the weather stripping isn't preventing alignment when fully closed.